# Bigquery will run query but not save view

Tags: google-bigquery

I have multiple tables, named tweet_stream_YYYMMDD and titles_by_followers, that I'm trying to join. The join works and the query returns a result when I limit it (it's too large without the limit). My problem comes when trying to save it as a view. I end up with a little pop up that says:

```
Failed to save view. Field 's.followersCount' not found.
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
       s.tweetId,
       s.text,
       s.retweeted,
       s.retweetCount,
       s.timestampMillis,
       s.userName,
       s.theUserID,
       s.followersCount,
       s.friendsCount,
       s.hashTags,
       s.urls,
       t.titles
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT tweetId, 
               text, 
               retweeted, 
               retweetCount, 
               timestampMillis,
               userName, 
               userID as theUserID, 
               followersCount, 
               friendsCount, 
               hashTags, 
               urls 
          FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([Testing.tweet_stream_],
                         TIMESTAMP('2016-07-29'),
                         TIMESTAMP('2016-08-12'))) as s
  INNER JOIN [Testing.titles_by_followers] as t
  ON s.theUserID = t.userID
  )
```

I haven't been able to find anything on SO or the official BQ issue and feature tracker so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this in the past, try to alias the fields, you will be hitting a weird internal regex that flags for error.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks. I gave that a try and aliased all the fields in my outer most select, and it's still giving me the error. Now it's just with the new alias I've assigned to s.followersCount. Any other ideas?